# Unity drag and drop problems on phone

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a drag and drop game for android.
When I press a shape it instantiates an object with that form and the object follows my finger. On unity editor, everything works fine but when I try it on phone it has some problems. If I lift the finger the object falls with a very high speed instead of the normal speed. And also if I hit with the object that is following my finger another object it goes through the second object. This happens only before I release the object. If I release it and then I put the finger on it, then it has the correct gravity and it can't go through other objects. 
This is my code.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Object_Spawm : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler 
{
    public float object_max_number;
    public Text object_number_text;
    public float object_number;
    //bool created = false;
    //public bool isOver = false;
    //public Transform object_to_spawn;

    public Transform prefab ;
    private Transform spawn;
    private bool isOver = false;
    public bool  created = false;


    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (spawn==null) {
            Debug.Log ("Mouse enter");
            isOver = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse exit");
        isOver = false;
    }

    void  Update() 
    {
        //Debug.Log (created);
        if (Input.touchCount == 0) {
            //created = false;

        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && spawn != null) {
            var pos = Input.mousePosition;
            pos.z = -Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            spawn.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            spawn = null;
            created = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        Event e = Event.current;
        if (object_number > 0)
        //if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && isOver ==true && spawn==null ){ //if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && isOver ==true ) 
        if(Input.touchCount == 1 && isOver == true && spawn==null){
            var pos = Input.mousePosition;
            pos.z = -Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
            spawn = Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;

            object_number -= 1;
            UpdateText ();
            created = true;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        object_number = object_max_number;
        UpdateText ();
    }


    void UpdateText()
    {
        object_number_text.text = object_number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use OnGUI method for anything. do everything in Update().

Comment: ok I will try this